# Blurring a UIPickerView's background

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am displaying a `UIPickerView` when tapping on a `UITableViewCell`. I am trying to add a `UIVisualEffectView` to the pickerView to give it a blurred background. What I'm ***trying*** to get is this:

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s111/sh/645d307f-c597-4dfa-890f-9404ed297e71/fd738fdf15cd956fcfa917e4311bfd1b

What I'm ***actually*** getting is this:

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s111/sh/27440e85-2181-49e1-89e0-4b57e0ce3783/e6e2abae0edfb705e915b03e1b37e008

Here is the code I'm using to create the blur and attach it to the picker:

```
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
[blurEffectView setFrame:_myPicker.frame];
[_myPicker addSubview:blurEffectView];
[_myPicker sendSubviewToBack:blurEffectView];
```

Notice that even with the call to `sendSubviewToBack`, this ends up putting the blur ***in front of*** the option wheel. If I look carefully when I scroll the view, I can see the options moving *behind* the blur.

How do I get the blur properly in the background and the option wheel on top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you do not know the exact view hierarchy of a UIPickerView I would simply recommend to give your pickerView `clearColor` as backgroundColor and to put the picker view as subview of your blurEffectView. This would be the right way to do this.