# swift - How to blur the background of UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

Is there a way to blur the background of UIPickerView so that the text or image below it is not so visible?

Comment: You should try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754716/blurring-a-uipickerviews-background.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121799/how-to-set-the-background-color-of-uipickerview-on-ios-7-using-sdk-7

Comment: everything is possible, therefore yes, there is a way to do that – take a quick look on the `UIVisualEffectView` class __[here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/)__.